# Surface area of a convex set less than that of its enclosing sphere?

Tags: geometry, analysis, convex-analysis

Is the boundary measure ("surface area") of a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ less than the boundary measure of it's enclosing hypersphere (smallest hypersphere that contains the set)?

In 2D I've found a paper that states it's true, and intuitively I think it should be true for n-D, but I'm having trouble proving it.

**Edit** Possible solution: approximate the boundary of the inner set with panels - line segments/triangles/tetrahedra/ect depending on the dimension. Then orthogonally project those panels onto the hypersphere. Since the set is convex, the projections of the panels don't overlap, and since the projections are orthogonal, their projections onto the sphere are larger than the original panels.

[image: 2D illustration]

**Edit 2** More general conjecture: If $X$ and $Y$ are convex sets with $X \subset Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $|\partial X| \le |\partial Y|$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem

Comment: Not really sure how that helps, could you elaborate? The statement is not true for non-convex sets (eg, draw a really wiggly curve inside a circle)

Comment: Can we assume the boundary is sufficiently smooth?

Comment: Only as smooth as a general convex set (differentiable almost everywhere I think).

Comment: This is not an answer; can't comment: Tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula?

Comment: Slice the convex set alongside $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes in a generic direction (you will probably need sard's theorem here). The result of such a slice again a convex set, and the slice of the outer circle is again circle (possibly bigger than the new outer circle, but never smaller). Now proceed by induction on $n$ and use fubini's theorem for the surface area of the outer circle from surface area of slices.

Comment: @qwert: Interesting link, it must be related.. I was actually working on proving a computable L1 Poincare inequality using the isoperimetric inequality (to understand it from another perspective than the way it's presented in my books), and this question naturally arose as a lemma I needed.

Comment: Smoothness shouldn't be a problem. Approximate the convex set $A$ from outside by $A_\epsilon$ the points at most $\epsilon$ distance from $A$. $A$ is convex so $\partial A$ is Lipschitz, therefore its Minkowski content exists, and is equal to the limit of the surface area of the (smooth) surface $\partial A_\epsilon$. So we can work with smooth approximations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let the set be $C$ and the sphere $S$.  Map $S$ onto $C$ so that $f(s)$ is the closest point to $s$ in $C$.  Then $f$ is a contraction, so it decreases Hausdorff measure of any dimension.

To see that $f$ is a contraction, let $f(s_1) = c_1$ and $f(s_2) = c_2 \ne c_1$.  Then
$(c_1 - c_2) \cdot (s_1 - c_1) \ge 0$ (otherwise you get a closer point to $s_1$ by moving from $c_1$ a short distance in the direction of $c_2$), and similarly
$(c_2 - c_1) \cdot (s_2 - c_2) \ge 0$.  Add these and rearrange to get
$\|c_1 - c_2\|^2 \le (c_1 - c_2) \cdot (s_1 - s_2)$, and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: This works once it is shown that $f$ is onto $C$.  Convexity of $C$, which was not used above, can be used to show that $f$ is onto.

Comment: for any point $c$ on the boundary of a convex set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a hyperplane $P$ containing $c$ and so that no points of $C$ lie on one of the sides of $P$.

Comment: Consider the point $s\in S$ on the side of $P$ that doesn't contain $C$ that is on the line perpendicular to $P$ and containing $c$. $f(s)=c$.

Comment: Convexity of $C$ was used in showing $f$ to be a contraction.

Comment: Ah, yes. The existence of a point between $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: It seems that this shows the more general conjecture because the proof doesn't use that S is a sphere (or even convex).