# If $u$ is a solution to the wave equation (Cauchy) then $|u(x,t)|\le A/t$ for some $A$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Let $u(x,t)$ be a solution for the Cauchy Problem
>
> $$u_{tt}-\Delta_xu = 0\mbox{ in $\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}$}$$
> $$u(x,0) = f(x)\mbox{ in $\mathbb{R}^3$}$$ $$u_t(x,0) = g(x) \mbox{in
>  $\mathbb{R}^3$}$$
>
> where $f$ and $g$ are of class $C^3$ and $C^2$ respectively in
> $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are null in the complementar of a compact. Show
> that there exists a constant $A$ such that
>
> $$|u(x,t)|\le A/t, x\in\mathbb{R}^3, t\ge 1$$
>
> Find, also, an estimative for the constant $A$ in terms of $f$ and
> $g$.

**UPDATE:**

I've found the solution [image]

but I need to understand why the intersection with the support is at most $4\pi R^2$. As I understand, the support of the data is the support of $f$. The intersection of $S_t(x)$ with this support should be what?

I'm trying to imagine the complement of the ball $B(0,R)$ which contains the support of $f$ (is the support $g$ necessary?). I must take the intersection with $S_x(t)$ but I do not know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the following [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58456/surface-area-of-a-convex-set-less-than-that-of-its-enclosing-sphere/58556#58556).

- If $C\subset\mathbb R^3$ is a convex set contained in a ball $B_R$, then $\mathcal H^2(\partial C)\leq \mathcal H^2(\partial B_R)=4\pi R^2$.

With your notation, let $E_x(t)$ be the ball bounded by $S_x(t)$ and let $B_R$ the ball that contains $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ and $\mathrm{supp}(g)$. Then $E_x(t)\cap B_R$ is convex and contained in $B_R$. Its surface is composed of two pieces, one of which is $\partial E_x(t)\cap B_R = S_x(t)\cap B_R$. Therefore
$$
\mathcal H^2\bigl(S_x(t)\cap B_R\bigr)
\leq \mathcal H^2\bigl(\partial(E_x(t)\cap B_R)\bigr)
\leq \mathcal H^2(\partial B_R)=4\pi R^2 .
$$

**Edit**

Obviously, I applied the initial *fact* with $C=E_x(t)\cap B_R$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal H^2$?

Comment: Two-dimensional Hausdorff measure. The surface area

Comment: Why is $C$, that is, $S_t(x)$ in my example, contained in $B_R$? I thought it was not necessairy contained

Comment: Read carefully. Where did I say that $S_x(t)\subset B_R$?

Comment: I thought $C$ was $S_x(t)$

Comment: I apply the _inital fact_ with $C=E_x(t)\cap B_R$, which is clearly contained in $B_R$